# Linear regression where undershooting isn't as bad as overshooting

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, approximation, regression

Given a set of points $(x_i, y_i)$, least-squares linear regression finds the linear function $L$ such that $$\sum \varepsilon(y_i, L(x_i))$$
is minimized, where $\varepsilon(y, y') = (y-y')^2$ is the squared error between the actual $y_i$ value and the one predicted by $L$ from $x_i$.

Suppose I want to do the same, but I want to use the following penalty function in place of $\varepsilon$:
$$
\epsilon(y, L(x)) = \cases{y-L(x) &  \text{if $y>L(x)+1$} \\
(y-L(x))^2 & \text{if $y\le L(x)+1$}}$$

If the fitted line passes a certain distance *below* the actual data point, I want to penalize it much less severely than if the line passes the same distance above the data point. (The threshhold for using the cheaper penalty function is $y > L(x)+1$ rather than $y > L(x)$ so that overshooting by some amount $\delta<1$ is not penalized less than undershooting by the same amount—we don't want to overpenalize $L$ for undershooting by too little!)

I could probably write a computer program to solve this numerically, by using a hill-climbing algorithm or something similar. But I would like to know if there are any analytic approaches. If I try to follow the approach that works for the usual penalty function, I get stuck early on, because there seems to be no way to expand the expression $\epsilon(y_i, mx_i+b)$ algebraically.

I expect that the problem has been studied with different penalty functions, and I would be glad for a reference to a good textbook.

Comment: `stats.stackexchange.com` would be much more familiar with this literature.

Comment: Thanks. If I don't get a good response here, I'll ask the mods to migrate the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the strict sense of the term, least squares methods deal with situations where
$$\epsilon(y,L(x))= (y-L(x))^2$$

Such errors lend themselves to easy modeling, via the [normal equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html). Others error metrics don't have such closed form solutions. They are usually iterative in nature.

The topic that you are looking for is its general method, the **penalty function** method. Just google it and you will find lots of references. [Here](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/~bryan/lottamath/penalty.pdf) is a nice place to start with. Let me know if you want anything specific.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I did not realize that the term "penalty function" was the correct one—it was just a lucky guess.

Comment: plz accept an answer, or at least update whether you found what you were looking  for!! Otherwise it is very difficult to make sense of what you want.

Comment: What's your hurry?

Comment: hahah.. no hurry. just wanted to know if I was helpful. Take your time.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your penalty function is not convex. I suggest
$$\begin{align}
\epsilon(r) &= \begin{cases}r & \text{if } r > 1 \\ \frac12 (r^2 + 1) & \text{if } r \le 1\end{cases} \\
&= r + \frac12\min(r-1,0)^2,
\end{align}$$
where $r=y-L(x)$. This is continuous, differentiable, convex, has minimum at $0$, and has a simple algebraic-ish form.

Nevertheless, I doubt there are any analytic solutions when piecewise polynomial functions are involved. One can observe that the net objective $\sum \epsilon(y_i-L(x_i))$ is piecewise quadratic, and the boundaries of the pieces are linear. So you could do quadratic programming over the current piece; if the solution lies on a boundary, switch to the adjacent piece; and repeat. I don't know if this will be any faster than doing a general nonlinear optimization, though, especially since the function seems nice enough (convex, differentiable, and hopefully not too badly scaled).

Comment: Seems to work well enough just by throwing it into Mathematica's `Minimize` routine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eQelS.png